# How to change "You must be logged in to post a comment."

Tags: comments, login, user-registration

Some of my users have mentioned that my site is confusing for them. As this is the case, I would like to actually make links to Login/Register for my unregistered visitors to quickly do so if they would like to leave a comment.

Right now it just says "You must be logged in to post a comment." with no link to Login. Where can I edit this and change it to "You must Register or Login to post a comment." with links to them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to modify it with the `comment_form_defaults` filter:

```
/**
 * Modify the "must_log_in" string of the comment form.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170492/26350
 */
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', function( $fields ) {
    $fields['must_log_in'] = sprintf( 
        __( '<p class="must-log-in">
                 You must <a href="%s">Register</a> or 
                 <a href="%s">Login</a> to post a comment.</p>' 
        ),
        wp_registration_url(),
        wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink() ) )   
    );
    return $fields;
});
```

where we use the [`wp_registration_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_registration_url) and [`wp_login_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url) core functions.

*ps: the [info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/comment_form_defaults) on the `comment_form_defaults` filter seems to be missing from the Codex.*

Comment: Thank you for the help. Sorry to be stupid but where do I put this, functions.php?

Comment: How about this part of the code wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) );

Comment: yes, that should work as well. I just wanted to emulate how it's done in the core. @BradDalton

Comment: Sure but why return apply_filters when modifying the default output for the text in a child theme?

Comment: I guess if the user was using that filter to modify the permalinks (like adding extra query strings), it would be consistent to apply it here also?

Comment: So you can't use that filter if its not returned in your custom filter function?

Comment: you don't need to add your own `the_permalink` filter, because this setup will  then just return the `get_permalink()` value.

Comment: Here is the codex link for `comment_form_defaults` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form_defaults/

Comment: Thanks for the update @theKing