# How do I change where "You must be logged in to comment" directs users?

Tags: functions, comments

I've seen a few answers to this question on this site, but none are current and none are very well explained. Is there any definitive answer to this question? It seems like a lot of folks want to know!

Comment: Are you sure none are current? Can you link to one you think needs better explanation?

Comment: The top two search results here look like they'd work to me, and I prefer this one: [using the comment_form_defaults filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170492/3276) over using a gettext filter. The comment_form_defaults filter is still called in 5.8.

Comment: That didn't work for me